# Response from Patch request using retrofit

Tags: android, httprequest, retrofit2

I was trying Patch request for first time to send id to server for changes and api is supposed to send me like this

> {
>     "result": "success",
>     "flag": "TKT_INVALID"
>   }

but what I am getting as response is

> Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=http://********.com/brosis/ticket/1791498663}

What I am doing here is using PATCH as just like GET request, because I haven't found any resource regarding it.
Can anyone point me to right direction

interface

```
@PATCH("ticket/{ticketId}/")
    Call<ResponseBody> getTicketVerified(@Body String empty,@Path("ticketId") String ticketId);
```

and calling it like

```
cdsService.getTicketVerified(" ",ticketNo).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                Log.v("TAGGGEw",response.toString());

                if(response.isSuccessful()) {

                    Log.d("TAGGGE", "posts loaded from API");
                    view.ticketVerified();
                }else {
                    int statusCode  = response.code();
                    view.HandleError(0);
                    Log.v("SplashScreenPresenter","Handling Server error");


                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {


                if(t instanceof IOException){
                    t.printStackTrace();
                    Log.v("TAGGGE","this is ioException");
                    view.HandleError(1);
                    Log.v("SplashScreenPresenter","Handling Network Error");
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: response.body() give your response

Comment: share code for `ResponseBody `

Comment: try this `Log.v("TAGGGEw",response.body().string());`

Comment: @Navneetヅ its just a plain response provided by OkHttp3

Comment: @DilipPoudel try using the model class that i have mentioned below in my answer

Comment: @DilipPoudel `response.body().string()` not `toString()` its `string()`. check that im sure youre getting correct response

Comment: @AbhishekSingh Tried it but no luck

Comment: what did you got? by printing that?

Comment: @AbhishekSingh I don't know why but nothing is printed at the Log.. not from try section and neither from the catch block

Comment: bro write that line top  in response section and check

Comment: @AbhishekSingh I have found that there is something wrong with API

Comment: @AbhishekSingh thanks for your time

Comment: you should firstly test api on postman or ARC then u need to implement

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
Log.v("TAGGGEw",response.toString());
```

by:

```
Log.v("TAGGGEw",new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
```

Comment: Then what I get is : okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@425461a8

Answer (score 0):

Use this model class instead of ResponseBody to fetch response

```
    public class ExampleJson {

@SerializedName("result")
@Expose
private String result;
@SerializedName("flag")
@Expose
private String flag;

public String getResult() {
return result;
}

public void setResult(String result) {
this.result = result;
}

public String getFlag() {
return flag;
}

public void setFlag(String flag) {
this.flag = flag;
}

}
```

interface

```
@PATCH("ticket/{ticketId}/")
Call<ExampleJson> getTicketVerified(@Body String empty,@Path("ticketId") String ticketId);
```

retrofit call

```
cdsService.getTicketVerified(" ",ticketNo).enqueue(new Callback<ExampleJson>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ExampleJson> call, Response<ExampleJson> response) {
            Log.v("TAGGGEw",response.body().toString());

            if(response.isSuccessful()) {

                Log.d("TAGGGE", "posts loaded from API");
                view.ticketVerified();
            }else {
                int statusCode  = response.code();
                view.HandleError(0);
                Log.v("SplashScreenPresenter","Handling Server error");


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ExampleJson> call, Throwable t) {


            if(t instanceof IOException){
                t.printStackTrace();
                Log.v("TAGGGE","this is ioException");
                view.HandleError(1);
                Log.v("SplashScreenPresenter","Handling Network Error");
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: I have used Responsebody many times .. Using PATCH is the real problem here I think. Because the body of response doesn't contain anything incase of PATCH

Comment: since you have `code=200, message=OK` your patch request is working as expected, issue should be with the response that you are returning

Comment: @DilipPoudel also check the output of `response.raw().body()`

Comment: Thanks for giving your time. I think there is some thing wrong with api